# nontype parameter of template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I saw some code like this:

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned M>  
bool compare (const char (&p1)[N], const char (&p2)[M])  
{  
    std::cout << "size : " << N << " " << M << std::endl;  
    return strcmp(p1, p2);  
}
```

The template does not take `typename` or `class` as parameters, but using `unsigned`, what is the usage of using nontype parameter of template?

In which case we should write template using non type parameter?

Comment: Please read some *introductory* book on C++. Select a book from [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).. whichever suits your taste and need.

Comment: I updated, basically I want to know when to use non type parameter template

Comment: Whenever you want to write a series of functions or classes that vary in a way depending not on a type, but on a constant.  In this case you will get a different function for each combination of array sizes.

Comment: can not be a const variable passed to the functions?

Comment: You have one use case in front of you: you can receive arrays of any size.